# How do I re-use a previously-collected Word dictionary

Tags: microsoft-word

I regularly add some words to my MS Word dictionary. When I install a new copy of it on my computer, it's painstaking to add all of them manually again. Is there a way to automate that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to file > options > proofing > customize dictionary.

[image]

Go to the file path and copy the file "CUSTOM.DIC" and keep it. After installing a new MS Office, copy the file to that path.

[image]